# ViewModel SaveStateHandle with Koin DI

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, savestate, koin

I try to preserve viewModel data against activity re-creation , but on onCreate() method from Fragment I got the following error : **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SavedStateProvider with the given key is already registered**

Even if the viewModel has never been create before, it causes a crash on the first app run

This is the relevent code:

//DI

```
  viewModel { (param: String) -> MyViewModel(param, get(), get(), get()) }
```

//Fragment

```
private lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = getStateViewModel() { parametersOf(args.param) 
}
```

//VM

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel()(
    private val param: String,
    private val savedState: SavedStateHandle,
    private val service1: Service1,
    private val service2: Service2
)
```

Any help?